# class is not key value coding-compliant while trying to get value

Tags: xcode, get, key

I set the following value: `[self.networkStream setProperty:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUsePassiveMode];` but before i do so i would like to check what value it currently has. But I am not able to find out how I can read its value.

I have a boolean variable, called "usepassive". What i need to do is compare the value above with usepassive.

I tried this:

```
BOOL status = [self.networkStream valueForKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUsePassiveMode];
if (status != usepassive)
        {
```

The result is an error: `[<__NSCFOutputStream 0x107d25d90> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key kCFStreamPropertyFTPUsePassiveMode.`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The counterpart to `[networkStream setProperty:... forKey:...]` is `[networkStream propertyForKey:...]`.
- `propertyForKey` returns an `id` (a pointer to an an Objective-C object), which can be 
  converted to a `BOOL` with `boolValue`.

So the following should work:

```
BOOL usePassive = [[self.networkStream propertyForKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUsePassiveMode] boolValue];
if (usePassive) {
    // passive mode enabled
} else {
    // passive mode disabled
}
```